# I see it = it is being seen by me

Tags: passive-voice

We can say:

> 1) I am seeing you

By

> 2) I see you

Then can we make a passive form out of it?

> 3) It is being seen by me

Or anyway it would be:

> 4) It is seen by me

Answer (score 1):

**The simple answer is, "yes, that's right."**

However, this introduces complex constructs that aren't always useful.  But first, a correction.

> (1) I am seeing you.
>
> (2) I see you.

Yes, these are the same thing, but U.S. native speakers would not use (1).  Specifically, we would not use that phrase.  I can remember using and hearing the phrase, "I'm not seeing it" (in reference, for example, to looking for a small object lost in the carpet), but we more commonly use "to look."

> (1a) I am looking at you.
>
> (2) I see you.

In other words, we use "to see" to describe the *fact* or state of beholding/seeing/looking-at something and "to look" to describe the *action* of beholding/seeing/looking-at something.

**And to answer your question**

In both these cases we can convert the sentence to passive-form.

> (3) You are being looked at (by me).
>
> (4) You have been seen (by me).

**And one last thing...**

Whether or not you need the final phrase identifying the person performing the action ("by me") depends on how you are using the sentence.  For example, it may not be important to specifically identify who is performing the action.

> "Who's making all that noise, Sandra?"
>
> "John," said Sandra, poking him in the arm.  "I think you've been seen."
>
> "Oh, I don't have time for this, Sandra.  Let's grab a Taxi, quick!"

In the above example, the person/people/thing/etc. making the noise is never identified because it's unimportant to the story.